# how to push to another branch

Tags: git, github

I have my local initialized git repo, I can push to my github repo via:

```
git push github master
```

Then, I decided to create another branch at my remote repo, named rails4

To push to the new brach, I tried:

```
git push github rails4
```

But, I get this error:

```
error: src refspec rails4 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/hopewise/dcaclab-website.git'
```

What do I miss?

**EDIT**

I found that I am trying to push to a different remote branch while my current local branch is at master, what I did is:

```
git branch rails4
git checkout rails4
git push github rails4
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `git branch` to your question?

Comment: @simo I followed your steps, getting no error but Im getting everything up to date but its not on the branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last argument to `git push`, in this case `rails4`, is a "refspec".  What this means, in this particular case, is that it has two parts: the branch name in *your* repository, and the branch you want to update or create in *their* repository.  (You put a colon between the two to separate them, e.g., `git push master:rails4` would copy *your* `master` to *their* `rails4`.)

You said `rails4`, which means `rails4:rails4`—if you omit the name for "their" side, it defaults to the same as the one for "your" side—so your git looked up your local `rails4` branch in order to push it ... and you don't *have* a local `rails4` branch, hence the slightly cryptic:

```
src refspec rails4 does not match any.
```

error message.

In other words, you must pick an existing branch in *your* repository (perhaps creating it first, so that it does exist) before you can push that branch to some other name, or even the same name, in *their* repository.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I can push from master branch to another branch at remote repo, please see EDIT

Comment: Yes, the `git branch rails4` created the branch `rails4` locally (at whatever commit was current when you did the `git branch` command).  After that, `git push github rails4` still means "push local rails4 branch to remote, calling it rails4 on the remote too", but now you have something to push.  Note: If there was already a remote `rails4`, a better sequence would be: `git fetch github; git checkout --track github/rails4` which would create local `rails4` at the same commit as remote-branch `github/rails4`, starting you out in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any commits on `rails4`? If not, it is pointing to same commit as your master branch. Try committing something on `rails4` and then pushing.

Alternatively, check the branches dropdown on github to see if your branch ref got pushed.

Comment: remote rails4 is beyond local rails4, do I have to pull rails4 first?

Comment: yup. You can't push on changes that are not in your local